# Running aliases in child sub project consisted of multiple other sub projects

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to invoke an alias in a child (sub) project which is consisted of multiple other sub projects, while running an alias from the parent project. You can check this [repo](https://github.com/yunerbekir/clojure-nested-eastwood) I am trying to run `lein sub eastwood` in the main project but I get an error. If I try the non-nested project it works.

Comment: Your `nested` sub-project references a `first` sub-sub-project, which does not exist (at least in the repo).  Either something is missing, or `nested` is just not supposed to have another sub-project?

Comment: @cfrick you mean that you cant access https://github.com/yunerbekir/clojure-nested-eastwood/tree/master/nested/first/src ? Because the nested project exists